# why this join on parent child tables results in wrong summarize?

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, inner-join, olap-cube

I am confusing writing this query to sum up the values of some table fields. the result summary is wrong. I simplify the design to easy understanding. 
the tables and fields are as follow:

```
Table [City] => {ID, CityName}
Table [A]    => {ID, CityID, Date, Value}
Table [B_1]  => {ID, AID, Value}
Table [B_2]  => {ID, AID, Value}
```

as you can see, table of [city] is parent of [A] and [A] is parent of [B_1] and [B_2]

this is the query:

```
SELECT     City.CityName, A.Date, SUM(A.Value), SUM(B_1.Value), SUM(B_2.Value)
FROM         A INNER JOIN
                      B_1 ON A.ID = B_1.AID INNER JOIN
                      B_2 ON A.ID = B_2.AID INNER JOIN
                      City ON A.CityID = City.ID
GROUP BY City.CityName, A.Date
```

assume that we have these values:

```
Data for Table [City] =>
ID  CityName
--  --------
1   LA
2   NYC

Data for Table [A] =>
ID  CityID  Date  Value 
--  ------  ----  -----
1   1       2014  8
2   1       2014  5 
3   2       2014  3

Data for Table [B_1] =>
ID  AID  Value 
--  ---  -----
1   1    3
2   1    6 
3   2    7
4   2    2

Data for Table [B_2] =>
ID  AID  Value 
--  ---  -----
1   1    8
2   1    5 
3   2    3
4   2    1
```

I am trying to achieve this results:

```
CityName  Date  AValue  B1Value  B2Value
--------  ----  ------  -------  -------
LA        2014  13      18       17
```

but the result is :

```
CityName  Date  AValue  B1Value  B2Value
--------  ----  ------  -------  -------
LA        2014  52      36       34
```

what is wrong???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are aggregating along different dimensions and getting a cross product for each "A".  You can solve this by pre-aggregating the results:

```
SELECT City.CityName, A.Date, SUM(A.Value), SUM(BVALUE1), SUM(BVALUE2)
FROM  A INNER JOIN
      (SELECT AID, SUM(VALUE) as BVALUE1
       FROM B_1
       GROUP BY AID
      ) B_1
      ON A.ID = B_1.AID INNER JOIN
      (SELECT AID, SUM(VALUE) as BVALUE2
       FROM B_2
       GROUP BY AID
      ) B_2
      ON A.ID = B_2.AID INNER JOIN
      City
      ON A.CityID = City.ID
GROUP BY City.CityName, A.Date;
```